# Use connect() and tr() without QObject::

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

I very often see that people are using `connect()` without `QObject::`.
How can i do that? When i write just `connect()` i get error:
`'connect' was not declared in this scope`

I can't use `using namespace QObject`, because QObject is class, not namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done when you're in a member function of a class inheriting from `QObject`. And when you're not in scope of an object inheriting from `QObject`, you should use the *object instance* and not scoping.

So for example:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    ...
    void myMemberFunction()
    {
        ...
        connect(...);  // Implicitly uses this->connect(...)
        ...
    }
    ...
};

void myNonmemberFunction(MyClass& instanceOfMyClass)
{
    ...
    instanceOfMyClass.connect(...)
    ...
}
```

Comment: So, in main() it is not possible? Can i do something like `auto *connect = &QObject::connect;`?

Comment: Yep you should use QObject::connect in `main` as it is not a member function of type derived from QObject

Comment: @Efog Ah, you want the *`static`* function? Then I'm actually not sure if you will get the correct function pointer. But *why* do you want to get the function pointer?

Answer (score 0):

For translation, you can use [`Q_DECLARE_TR_FUNCTIONS`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#Q_DECLARE_TR_FUNCTIONS) ([example here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/i18n-source-translation.html#translating-non-qt-classes)).

For connects, the [QObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) class defines a lot of static connect methods.